# Laravel 5.4 home page redirects me to login instead

Tags: laravel

I used laravel Authentication, I have 2 main pages: 
Home: where there should be login and register
And Dashboard, that the user is redirected to after login.
My problem is that the route '/home' is automaticaly being redirected to login page first

Comment: Can you please post some code? Specifically, your `routes/web.php`

Comment: We need to see code to know what's going on. Have you tried logging in and then navigating to '/home'?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behaviour. The standard auth-system provides `'auth'` middleware. Which prevents unauthenticated users from visiting the `/home` path. If you register and login. You will get redirected to the `/home` route.

Take a look at the docs for Authentication and also maybe for middleware.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication